# Array Key 0 instead of the string only for JSON encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm attempting to use json_encode on a php array. I have to structure the returned JSON as:

```
[
  {"text": "Title1"},
  {"text": "URL"}
]
```

I've tried the following, but I keep getting 0 as a key.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$title1 = $xml->results->result->jobtitle;
$snippet1 = $xml->results->result->snippet;
$url1 = $xml->results->result->url;




$arrays = array('text'=>$title1);
echo json_encode($arrays);
```

What am I doing wrong with my encoded array? How do I have it so that it doesn't return as 0?

```
 {"text":{"0":"CDL-A Dry Bulk Drivers Wanted - Regional - OH, WV, PA"}}
```

Comment: could you attach the value of the variable $url?

Comment: Can you include an example of what the XML file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this: You have no mistake in json_encode.

```
$title1 = $xml->results->result->jobtitle;
```

...

```
$arrays = array('text'=>$title1[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

They way you are setting your array is incorrect. What you want to do is.

```
$array = [
    ['text' => 'hello'],
    ['text' => 'hello again'],
];

$encoded = json_encode($array);

print_r($encoded);
```

which returns

```
[
    {"text":"hello"},
    {"text":"hello again"}
]
```

Comment: My mistake. Didn't catch that 'jobtitle' is returned as an array making Hamid Sardar answer correct as indicated.